# Is the python thread method different in IDLE and pycharm?

Tags: python, multithreading

In fact, I run and debug these codes as below in both IDLE(Python 3.5.2 shell ) and Pycharm Community Edition 2017.2.
But when I run the code many times, I found there are some questions confused me. The code run in pycharm generates this result:

- Thread-3 processing One
  Thread-1 processing Two
  Thread-3 processing Three
  Thread-2 processing Four
  Thread-3 processing Five
  Thread-1 processing Six
  Thread-2 processing Seven
  Thread-1 processing Eight

The code run in pycharm generates this result:

- Thread-1 processing One
  Thread-2 processing Two
  Thread-3 processing Three
  Thread-1 processing Four
  Thread-2 processing Five
  Thread-3 processing Six
  Thread-1 processing Seven
  Thread-2 processing Eight

**As you can see, "1 3 2 3 1 2 1" and "2 3 1 2 3 1 2". I run many times and find this. So I just want to know, why the thread method is different in different IDE? And could you please tell me some good directions for learning thread in Python3?**

```
import queue
import threading
import time

exitFlag = 0


class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, q):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.q = q

    def run(self):
        print("Open Thread：" + self.name)
        process_data(self.name, self.q)
        print("Exit Thread：" + self.name)


def process_data(threadName, q):
    while not exitFlag:

        queueLock.acquire()
        if not workQueue.empty():
            data = q.get()
            print("%s processing %s" % (threadName, data))
            queueLock.release()
        else:
            queueLock.release()
        time.sleep(1)


threadList = ["Thread-1", "Thread-2", "Thread-3"]
nameList = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"]
queueLock = threading.Lock()
workQueue = queue.Queue(10)
threads = []
threadID = 1

for tname in threadList:
    thread = myThread(threadID, tname, workQueue)
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)
    threadID += 1

queueLock.acquire()
for word in nameList:
    #print(workQueue.empty())
    workQueue.put(word)
    #time.sleep(1)
queueLock.release()

while not workQueue.empty():
    pass

exitFlag = 1

for t in threads:
    t.join()

print("Exit Main Thread")
```

Comment: It's just a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), and it's a real pain to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads **don't gurantee** that they will execute in **any order**, thats why you are getting different results on differents executions.
So the **threads are not dependant on IDE**